# Android: app won't run unless you update google play services

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I found out long in the site, but I didn't find a solution for my problem. The emulator said me that the app won't run unless I update google play services. I installed the google play services in the sdk manager, I think it's a gradle problem but I don't know what it is.

Here is my gradle Project:

```
buildscript 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies 
  {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
  }
}

allprojects 
{
  repositories 
  {
    jcenter()
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) 
{
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my gradle app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
  defaultConfig 
  {
    applicationId "com.example.utente.myfirebase"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes 
{
  release 
  {
  minifyEnabled false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-
  rules.pro'
  }
}
}

dependencies 
{
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Details of the emulator:

```
Name: Nexus_5_API_22 CPU/ABI: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86) Path: 
C:\Users\Utente\.android\avd\Nexus_5_API_22.avd Target: google_apis [Google 
APIs] (API level 22) Skin: nexus_5 SD Card: 100M hw.dPad: no         
runtime.network.speed: full hw.accelerometer: yes hw.device.name: Nexus 5 
vm.heapSize: 64 skin.dynamic: yes hw.device.manufacturer: Google hw.gps: yes 
hw.initialOrientation: Portrait image.androidVersion.api: 22 hw.audioInput: 
yes image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-22\google_apis\x86\ tag.id: 
google_apis showDeviceFrame: yes hw.camera.back: emulated hw.mainKeys: no 
AvdId: Nexus_5_API_22 hw.camera.front: emulated hw.lcd.density: 480 
avd.ini.displayname: Nexus 5 API 22 hw.gpu.mode: auto hw.device.hash2: 
MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88 hw.ramSize: 1536 hw.trackBall: no 
hw.battery: yes hw.cpu.ncore: 2 hw.sdCard: yes tag.display: Google APIs 
runtime.network.latency: none hw.keyboard: yes hw.sensors.proximity: yes 
disk.dataPartition.size: 800M hw.sensors.orientation: yes avd.ini.encoding: 
UTF-8 hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen how can I do that?

Comment: yes make sure your Google Play service from SDK manager is upto date,and you have also download all google services for the same version of your emulator is , and delete the current one and after update create a new emulator with same config,thanks

Comment: @9spl how can I set the Google Play services in my emulator?

Comment: change this line to and it will work compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'

Comment: @9spl it gives me a lot of errors

Comment: @9spl oh I had to change both the auth and the database to 9.4.0! Many thanks!